# Padding erased when resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, padding

I have a website and the first two pages are giving me problems. http://www.readysetpixel.net/about.html and http://www.readysetpixel.net/faq.html

The padding for the content is set to 20px and when I set it to when the browser resizes to 800px the max-height switches to 490px for the content as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
     if ($(this).height() <= 800){
      $('.content').css('max-height', '490px'); //sets max-height
     } else{
  $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //deletes max-height
   }
 }).resize()
})
</script>
```

All of this works fine in google chrome but in firefox and IE they ignore the padding at the bottom for some reason.  I have tried to add

```
  $('.pad').css('padding-bottom', '20px'); //sets padding
```

and then delete is the same way the max-height and that will work but then it gives google an extra 20px of padding when resized.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED:

The sayhello and contest page were doing the same thing.  For some reason when I used the padding with the form it reads it correctly in firefox and IE and chrome.  Which is strange because if I do the same thing for the previous two pages it give chrome an extra 20px of padding.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using javascript instead of [@media tags](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), seems like the perfect use case and it might be a little cleaner/easier to maintain?  Padding seems to be working in my Chrome v21, FF v14 and Safari v6.

Comment: How do I achieve what I want using @media.  I tried previously but couldn't do it.

Comment: @media screen and (max-height: 800px) {
  .content {max-height: 490px;}
}

Comment: ^^ That's what I used but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I was not offering it as a solution to your padding problem... just a suggestion instead of all that javascript.  I did see [this article](https://shanetomlinson.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-padding-and-min-height-bug-in-firefox-and-ie/) which kind of sounds the same, does seem like a bug because the padding is there (just not rendered).

Comment: Check my update thing.  See if you might be able to help

Comment: The answer does get you cross browser without adding padding-bottom to all the pages right?  Do you need a fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this is a rendering bug because the margin-bottom is not being added to the height calculation ([FF & IE Render Bug Article](https://shanetomlinson.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-padding-and-min-height-bug-in-firefox-and-ie/)).  Fixing the symptom across browsers should not be too hard; you can just move the height calculations down a layer (out of the scroll layer).

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>...</h1>
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the `.scroll` would be responsible for the `height` & `overflow`; while the `.content` would be responsable for the `width` & `padding`.  Not the most elegant solution but it will solve your cross browser problem.

If you want me to setup a fiddler just let me know.

Unrelated Side Note: After examining you CSS, your site might benefit some OOCSS approaches (definitely cut down on the size of your css file if you worry about that sort of thing).